# $('body').height() changing unpredictably

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

My goal is to have a white div (#containMe) stretch to the full height of the document, regardless of window size or how much content I have on the page.

I put my HTML head and JQuery in a PHP document and use PHP's require_once to put that header onto each page. However, when I've got #containMe set to the document's height with Jquery, it tries to set it to the body height instead. The body's height also seems to change each time I refresh, causing #containMe's height to change unpredictably.

The document's height appears to stay consistent, but the body's height fluctuates, and #containMe is trying to stick to the body's height instead of the document's. This happens with Chrome, Android Chrome, and Firefox. I tried the following:

```
$('body').height($(document).height());
```

But it seemed to have no effect.

Here's my Jquery in my head:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#containMe").height($(document).height());
        $("#containMe").width($(document).width() - 200);
        $('.dropdown').hover(function () {
        $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click');
      });
    });
</script>
```

(Note that the bootstrap dropdown is still working)

Here's my relevant CSS:

```
body
{
    background: #333577 url(bg1.png);
    height: 100%;
}

html
{
    height: 100%;
}

#containMe
{
    background: white;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #111111;
}
```

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
    <div id="containMe" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container-fluid jumbotron text-center"><h1>Web Pofrtfolio</h1>
            <h2>By Rhea Herrmann</h2></div>
```

And here's a link to the page where the problem is occurring.
http://www.rheaherrmann.com/other/wiki.php

If you scroll to the bottom and keep refreshing, the div's height appears to fluctuate. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try in css for #containMe `height:100vh; ' I hop the problem will be solved.

Comment: Just tried that. It looks like it had no effect. But thank you! @RiotZeastCaptain

Comment: Okay @Rhea , what exactly you need ?

Comment: I need #containMe's height to match the full height of the page, but it fluctuates. If you look at the page itself and refresh a few times, the div's height goes up and down, sometimes filling the page height and sometimes not. It looks like it's trying to match the body's height instead of document's. @RiotZeastCaptain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm getting this right i think you could do the following and everything should be as you expect it to be:

- Remove `#containMe`'s height from the CSS, don't use any height at all.
- Remove `.container-fluid` in `.jumbotron`. Since you already have a `.container-fluid` class above you don't need another `.container-fluid`, and as bootstrap's documentation states: containers are not nestables: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container.
- Remove the `.container-fluid` class next to `.innards` (for the same reason as above). If you need to keep the paddings as it was, you could use `.col-sm-12`.
- Remove or comment any javascript code that modify the height of `#containMe`.

Please let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: You and @Wolf_t helped me out a ton. I completely misinterpreted what .container-fluid was for. I made the edits you suggested and manually set the width of #containMe in the CSS, and now it's golden. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

-Use 100vh instead of 100% in your css for #containMe.

-Don't nest containers with bootstrap. "Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable." http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container

Comment: I gave that a try, but the problem's still occurring. Thank you though!

Comment: Hey could you post your html? I'm inspecting your page and it seems to me that you are manually setting the height as style="height: 1253px; width: 940px;" in your containme div tag

Comment: When i get rid of the style="height: 1253px; width: 940px;" in your div tag for #containMe, your containMe div is perfectly fitting the screen's height. As for why some of your others tags are over flowing, you should look into your  class="container-fluid innards" tag because that is pushing out of your containMe tag. Good luck!

Comment: I updated the first post with the HTML. That's an interesting thing to bring up though. Something else appears to be adding the style attribute straight into the HTML.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container
Look at the documentation. I think your problem is has to due with bootstrap. "Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable." You are nesting multiple containers in your html

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var windowheight = $(document).height();
  var windowwidth = $(document).width() - 200;
  //alert (windowheight);
  $('#containMe').css('height', windowheight + 'px');
  $("#containMe").css('width' ,windowwidth + 'px' );
  $('.dropdown').hover(function () {
      $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click');
  });
});
```

Use this in the JS

Comment: I gave that a try. It looks like it's trying to use the window height instead of the document's height. This is the page I'm testing on: http://www.rheaherrmann.com/other/wikitest.php

Comment: Update your complete code in jsfiddle, to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of

```
height: [whatever];
```

In your #containMe class in the style sheet and remove it from your element style(the style attribute of the #containMe div). It has to be gone from both places.